# Is it okay to have class level variables in Symfony controller class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, frameworks

I have a project that uses Symfony framework. For optimisation purposes I have narrowed down 6 common variables which are being used constanly during a request. Some of this variables are inside database.

Now, it is bad practise to go back to database again and again 5 times, getting same values. So, I thought of storing those variable value into class level variable.

Is it a good practise?

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    /*Class level variables to eliminate repetitive object creation.*/
    protected $doctrine;
```

Comment: This is not a "class level variable" (aka static variable). It's an instance variable.

Comment: Where/how do you want to share those variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create another `extends` between your controller and base controller of symfony. Like this:

```
class YourController extends ApplicationController

class ApplicationController extends Controller
```

and ApplicationController could have methods like this:

```
/**
* @var User
*/
protected  $loggedUser = false ;
protected function getLoggedUserOrNull()
{
    if ( $this->loggedUser === false )
        $this->loggedUser =  $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser() ;
    return $this->loggedUser ;
}
```

This example shows that instance of logged User is "cached"; that is what you need right? You could use the same idea for other things you need often.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is a good practice. The only very slight disadvantage is that if the value somehow changes in the database from the time you assign it to the class variable to when you access it again. But chances are fairly slim